# AWK - Transmission of a variable with getline to system ()?

Tags: awk, getline

I have a theoretical question:

1) How pass a variable to the system of getline ()?

```
awk 'BEGIN{var="ls"; var | getline var; system("echo $var")}'
```

2) How to assign a variable the output system ("ls") and print the result in awk?

```
awk 'BEGIN{var="system("ls")"; print '$var'}'
```

3) Can you assign a variable in the system (var = "ls") and print the result in awk?

```
awk 'BEGIN{system(var="ls"); print "'"$var"'"}'
```

Thank you for the information.

**EDIT:**

**torek**: Thank you for your response.

I understand that in the first example, you can do this:

```
awk 'BEGIN { while ("ls -l" | getline var) system("echo " var  );}'
```

For this application, you can not assign a variable output from system ()? As in this example:

```
awk 'BEGIN {var="ls -l"; system(var); print var}'
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're looking at this the wrong way, I think.  Awk's `system` just takes any old string, so give it one, e.g.:

```
system("echo " var);  # see side note below
```

(remember that in awk, strings are concatenated by adjacency).  Moreover, `system` just runs a command; to capture its output, you need to use `getline`, similar to your question #1.

If you want to read all the output of `ls` you need to loop over the result from `getline`:

```
awk 'BEGIN { while ("ls" | getline var) print "I got: " var; }'
```

Since this defines only a `BEGIN` action, `awk` will start up, run `ls`, collect each output line and print it, and then exit.

---

Side note: be very careful with variables passed to a shell (this includes both calls to `system` and items on the left hand side of `| getline`, plus some other cases in modern varieties of `awk`—anything that runs a command).  Backquotes, `$(command)`, and semicolons can all allow users to invoke arbitrary commands.  For instance, in the `system("echo " var)` example above, if `var` contains `; rm -rf $HOME` the command becomes `echo ; rm -rf $HOME`, which is almost certainly not something you want to have happen.

You can check for "bad" characters and either object, or quote them.  Modern 8-bit-clean shells should only require quoting quotes themselves (for syntactic validity), `$`, `<`, `>`, `|`, and `` ` ``.  If you use single quotes to quote arguments (to make them appear as a single "word"), you need only escape the single quotes.  See [this unix.stackexchange.com answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/64218) for more details.

---

One other side note: I tend to add "unnecessary" semicolons to my awk scripts, making them look more like C syntactically.  Old habit from decades ago.

Comment: torek: Thank you for your response.
For this application, you can not assign a variable output from system ()? As in this example:
`awk 'BEGIN {var="ls -l"; system(var); print var}'`

Comment: The `system` function: (1) runs something to completion; then (2) returns its exit value.  `ls` has an exit value of 0 on success.  So, you can do `x = system(foo); print "ran " foo " and got " x;` for instance.  If `foo` is the string `"ls"`, this will run `ls` with output going to awk's stdout, and set `x` to 0 because `ls` will succeed.

Comment: Note that it is important to **escape** user-supplied parameters as shown in [this Unix.SE answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/64218/8250). Consider this example: `awk '{ system("echo " $0); }'. This command is supposed to show every line from a file, but a line such as `bye; rm /etc/passwd` will cause `bye` to be printed before your `/etc/passwd` file gets removed.

Comment: @Lekensteyn: agreed.  The examples above were using known fixed (hard-coded) *inputs* like `"ls"` and trying to capture the *output*.  As always, if users are allowed to generate *inputs*, someone must verify and/or encode them before passing them on.  Otherwise [Little Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/) wreaks havoc.

Comment: @torek Yesterday I was also thinking of mommy exploit :P But in this context, `; DROP TABLE students` does not make sense unless you have a command `DROP`. Can you add something about escaping input to your answer? I see the OP doing `system("echo " var)` which is definitely a bad idea.