# Error calling system() within awk

Tags: bash, shell, awk, syntax-error

I'm trying to execute a system command to find out how many unique references a csv file has in its first seven characters as part of a larger awk script that processes the same csv file. There are duplicate entries and I don't want awk to parse the whole file twice so I'm avoiding NR. The gist of this part of the script is:

```
#!/bin/bash
awk '
{
  #do some stuff, then when finished, count the number of unique references
  productFile="BusinessObjects.csv";
  systemCall = sprintf( "cat %s | cut -c 1-7 | sort | uniq | wc -l", $productFile );
  productCount=`system( systemCall )`-1; #subtract 1 to remove column label row
}' < BusinessObjects.csv
```

And the interpreter doesn't like it:

`awk: cmd. line:19: ^ syntax error ./awkscript.sh: line 38: syntax error near unexpected token '(' 
./awkscript.sh: line 38: systemCall = sprintf( "cat %s | cut -c 1-7 | sort | uniq | wc -l", $productFile );`

If I hard-code the system command

```
productCount=`system( "cat BusinessObjects.csv | cut -c 1-7 | sort | uniq | wc -l" )`-1;
```

I get:

`./awkscript.sh: command substitution: line 39: syntax error near unexpected token '"cat BusinessObjects.csv | cut -c 1-7 | sort | uniq | wc -l"'
./awkscript.sh: command substitution: line 39: 'system( "cat BusinessObjects.csv | cut -c 1-7 | sort | uniq | wc -l" )'`

Technically, I could do this outside of awk at the start of the shell script, store the result in a system variable, and then pass it to awk using -v, but it's not great for the readability of the awk script (it's a few hundred lines long). Do I have a space or quotes in the wrong place? I've tried fiddling, but I can't seem to present the call to system() in a way that the interpreter will accept. Finally, is there a more sensible way to do this?

---

**Edit:** the csv file is indeed semicolon-delimited, so it's best to cut using the delimiter rather than the number of chars (thanks!).

> ProductRef;Data1;Data2;etc
>
> 1234567;etc;etc;etc

---

**Edit 2:**
I'm trying to parse a csv file whose first column is full of N unique product references, and create a series of associated HTML pages that include a "Page n of N" information field. It's (painfully obviously) the first time I've used awk, but it seemed like an appropriate tool for parsing csv files. I'm trying to hence count and return the number of unique references. At the shell

> cut -d\; -f1 BusinessObjects.csv | sort | uniq | wc -l

works fine, but I can't get it working inside awk by doing

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -n "$1" ]
then
        productFile=$1
else
        echo "Missing product file argument."
        exit
fi

awk -v productFile=$productFile '
BEGIN {
        FS=";";
        productCount = 0;
        ("cut -d\"\;\" -f1 " productFile " | sort | uniq | wc -l") | getline productCount;
        productCount -=1; #remove the column label row
}

{
print productCount;
}'
```

I get a syntax error on the cut code if I don't wrap the semicolon in \"\;\" and the script just hangs without printing anything when I do.

Comment: Why is it in backticks ?Also Why is sprintf not quoted ?Also why `$productFile`. This script is a mess

Comment: Could you add a snippet of BusinessObjects.csv? If there is a column delimiter you could also use something like cut –d’;’ -f1 yourFile

Comment: @Jidder, I originally had productCount=system( sprintf( "cat %s | cut -d';' | sort | uniq | wc -l", productFile ) )-1; then started fiddling to try to find the syntax error and it turned into frankencode as I got confused between bash and awk.

Comment: This can all be done in awk though i dont know why you are using a system call. What exactly is it you are trying to do. Can you post expected output ?

Comment: What do you mean you are avoiding NR as you dont want it to parse the file twice ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't remember that you can use backticks in awk.

```
  productCount=`system( systemCall )`-1; #subtract 1 to remove column label row
```

You can read your output by not using system and running your command directly, and using getline instead:

```
  systemCall | getline productCount
  productCount -= 1
```

Or more completely

```
  productFile = "BusinessObjects.csv"
  systemCall = "cut -c 1-7 " productFile " | sort | uniq | wc -l"
  systemCall | getline productCount
  productCount -= 1
```

- No need to use `sprintf` and include `cat`.
- Assigning strings to variables is also optional. You can just have `"xyz" | getline ...`.
- `sort | uniq` can just be `sort -u` if supported.
- Quoting may be necessary if filename has spaces or characters that may confuse the command.
- `getline` may alter global variables differently from expected. See https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Getline.html.

Comment: Thanks, I've added an edit that adapts your approach to the goal I'm trying to achieve. Unfortunately, I'm still having trouble making the bash code execute through getline and don't understand why.

Comment: @user48493 You shouldn't enclose the string around `()`.

Comment: Also `{ print productCount; }` would never run without a file.

Comment: I also recommend applying print statements around so you can trace the runtime of your awk code.

Comment: You're right, your advice fixed the problem. Adding a print statement alerted me that the interpreter had left the BEGIN block and didn't have a file to read in my stripped-down test script. Thank you.

Comment: Additionally, I realised that my original code had a comment line immediately above with an apostrophe in a word, which was disactivating the awk interpreter and confusing me (the `getline` code was returning a syntax error accross two different lines when in fact the syntax was nominally OK). Lesson learned: #don't do this!

Answer (score 0):

Could something like this be an option?

```
$ cat productCount.sh
#!/bin/bash
if [ -n "$1" ]
then
        productCount=`cat $1 | cut -c 1-7 | sort | uniq | wc -l`
        echo $productCount
else
        echo "please supply a filename as parameter"
fi

$ ./productCount.sh BusinessObjects.csv
9
```

Comment: Thank you, but I really wanted to know if I could do this within awk using system(), rather than calling the bash code at the start of the script and then passing productCount to awk using -v. Or, if this is bad practice, an explanation why.

Comment: Maybe this answers your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10008407/awk-transmission-of-a-variable-with-getline-to-system